# EF Core FluentAPI Multiple Field Issue

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-fluent-api

I have inherited some code which is now causing an issue w. The code looks similar to the following (albeit redacted).

```
public class ObjectX {
   public Guid Id { get; set; }
   public List<ObjectY> ListOfY { get; set; }
}

public class ObjectY {
   public Guid Id { get; set; }
   public ObjectX MyX { get; set; }
   public ObjectZ MyZ { get; set; }
}

public class ObjectZ
   public Guid ObjectXId { get; set; }
   public Guid ObjectYId { get; set; }
   public ObjectX MyX { get; set; }
   public ObjectY MyY { get; set; }
}
```

So just to be clear,

- ObjectX contains a collection of ObjectY
- ObjectY contains an instance of ObjectZ and ObjectX
- ObjectZ contains an instance of both ObjectX and ObjectY

ModelBuilder has the following:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ObjectZ>
.HasIndex(p => new { p.ObjectXId, p.ObjectYId })
.IsUnique();
```

indicating that **ObjectX** and **ObjectY** are unique as a pair but can appear in different combinations.

The query that is being used is

```
var something = context.ObjectX
                  .Where(x => x.Id = <somevalue>)
                  .Include(y => y.ListOfY)
                     .ThenInclude(z => z.MyZ)
                  .SingleOrDefault();
```

The issue I'm encountering is that while the ThenInclude function successfully retrieves the first ObjectZ that matches ObjectY.Id, it doesn't take into account ObjectX.Id.

Is there a way to adjust the query, Fluent definitions, or other aspects to ensure that ObjectX is returned with a list of ObjectY where ObjectY.MyZ matches both ObjectXId and ObjectYId?

I acknowledge that the current state of the database design and other related components may not be optimal, but as previously mentioned, I inherited this setup.

Comment: What is the relationship between ```ObjectX``` and ```ObjectZ``` one-to-one or one-to-many?

Comment: Why you need ObjectY model... Same thing can be done by only 2 model i.e ObjectX and ObjectY

Comment: @DarkkL It's not that simple. There can be many ObjectZ with the same ObjectX but each MUST have a different ObjectY. ObjectX/ObjectY combination has one-to-one with with ObjectZ.

Comment: @Ravi - granted but as I said the inherited code is rubbish. The database and code has far too many redundant relationships. There's no reason in many cases why I can't navigate through intermediate objects A -> B -> C but the code has just about every possible navigation defined.